# Kind of NSScrollView not found

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsscrollview

How do I do badges like this attached to a NSScrollView? I don't know if it's a custom framework but it looks like a modifies NSScrollView.

[image: ScrollView]

Thanks, MCPP.

Comment: And what about that image do you want? The badges ?

Comment: Yes, and the grouping using text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not the scroll view that gives the effect you are after, but the `NSOutlineView` configured as a source list.

In order to get the badges, etc. you'll have to work on the data display, which is implemented differently if you use a cell based or a view based `NSOutlineView`.

Since `NSOutlineView` is a subclass of `NSTableView` you should make sure you read the documentation for both, as the `NSOutlineView` docs presume knowledge of the workings of its super class.

The docs for [NSOutlineView](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSOutlineView_Class/Reference/Reference.html) will give you the initial starting point, but be prepared to do some digging of your own.

There is a demo project from Apple [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/SourceView/Introduction/Intro.html), but notice that it uses an `NSTreeController`, which you may or may not wish to do in your own implementation.

Comment: Thanks - exactly what i searched for!